# ImportError: Could not import settings 'LJ.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named code

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, mongoengine

This is what the outhput is when I run `python manage.py runserver`. I am using mongodb as my backend and django as the framework, the version used are : mongoengine 0.5.2, pymongo 2.7.2 and python 2.7.3

```
python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'LJ.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named code
```

Answer (score 0):

You import module named `code` somewhere in your settings file.  Run this command

```
python LJ/settings.py
```

and read stacktrace to get exact line where the error occurs.

Comment: the error is shown as : File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pymongo.code
ImportError: No module named code- How do i resolve it?

Comment: Looks like you use old version of mongoengine. See https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/509

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: on the terminal used the following command : apt-get install python-mongoengine